# Edited song info in VLC - now won't open in any other player

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player, windows-media-player, metadata

Basically what it says in the title. I have a CD ripped to WMA with Windows Media Player, which I opened with VLC Media Player in order to edit the track info. Apparently it uses an unusual file format to do that, because now Windows doesn't display track info for these files anymore like it does for others (columns are there but blank for these files), and they won't play in Windows Media Player (the other player I thought most likely to play WMA files) nor Winamp (my music player of choice.)

Is there any way to edit the metadata back into a more broadly readable format? Or some other way to play these files again in anything other than VLC?

Comment: Could the real file type accidentally differ from the extension?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Could be - how would I tell for sure?

Comment: Try trid from http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html, or other application or online tools. If you use trid, you'll need both the executable and latest filetype definitions.